# when he was under the influence of

Tags: clauses, ambiguity, post-modifier

> a. A discussion of his behavior when he was under the influence of medications was helpful to him.
>
> b.  A discussion of his behavior, when he was under the influence of medications, was helpful to him.

Do the commas change anything?

Can we tell whether

1. the discussion took place when he was under the influence of medications

or whether

2. what was discussed was the behavior he had when he was under the influence of medications

?

Comment: The commas make it *less* clear. "*When*" does nothing to help. This is no worse: "A discussion of his behavior under the influence of medications was helpful to him." It is the words *discussion* and *behaviour* that need separating. This would be clearer: "His behavior under the influence of medications was later discussed, which he found helpful."

Answer (score 1):

The commas mark the phrase between them as extra information, however marking this marking doesn't clear up the basic ambiguity in the grammar.

The pragmatic meaning would take account of our background knowledge of what was being discussed, who he was discussing with, where, when and why he was having this discussion, and whether he was actually under the influence of medication (singular) at the time.  We don't have any of that:

> Two weeks after stopping taking statins, and three weeks after the incident, John returned to his GP. A discussion of his behaviour when he was under the influence of the medication was helpful to him.

> Jack's behaviour had become increasingly bizarre until he was arrested and detained in a mental institute. In the hospital, Jack began taking the anti-psychotic mediation, which calmed his anxieties and suppressed some of his hallucinations. A discussion of his behaviour when he was under the influence of the medication was helpful to him.

Same sentence, different context, different meaning.  Commas wouldn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it changes the meaning entirely.

```
a. A discussion of his behavior when he was under the influence of medications was helpful to him.

b. A discussion of his behavior, when he was under the influence of medications, was helpful to him.
```

In sentence *a*, the discussion is about a period of time in the past when this man was medicated.  This sentence makes sense.

In sentence *b*, the discussion took place while he was medicated. "Under the influence" can be serious, as in "under the influence of alcohol," which is another way of saying "intoxicated."  This sentence is an object lesson in how not to places commas.